# Cache social streams

Tags: javascript, json, performance, caching, cdn

We do an import from Facebook, Instagram and Twitter on a lot of artistpages, so the users can find get the newest updates from that particular artist. However since we want to import about 5 updates and we're keen to get the pageload to about 1 second, we need some kind of smart caching of the content. We're a part of a bigger organization, so we dont pay for our CDN traffic, so I've though of using them to the max.

**My idea for a flow:**
First user do an fully import -> images and text gets saved in JSON which gets stored locally on users computer and on server/CDN for other users. When a new user enters the page, the JSON gets imported, which will import images and text too. in the background we check if new updates are available and we'll add those to the stream. If new updates, these gets added to the JSON. Old updates gets removed. If a user have visited the site before the user will get the JSON from his/her cache.

Does anyone know of a better way? We develop it in BackboneJS

Answer (score 0):

Just set a limit of the latest "updates" or "posts".

Comment: Do you think that would change much? Importing images from instagram can take a few seconds each time whereas my own images from my server and CDN takes miliseconds

Comment: Sure, just give them the oppinion to change the limit and see more updates.

Comment: And I wouldn't cache these posts, because if one post got deleted it will still exist on your website.